# Is judging a person blindly a sin?

Tags: karma, sin

Is judging a person blindly or using poor judgement to judge someone discouraged in Hinduism? Is it a sin? If yes what punishment would be granted for committing such a sin.?

**EDIT:** Blind judgement may also include
`Forming an opinion WITHOUT  careful thought. And believing such opinion to be completely true or factual without doing any verification or research. For example, if a person say Mr. A accuses Mr. B of committing a certain crime. And if Mr. C blindly believes Mr. A's accusation to be true without asking Mr. A to provide any evidence. Is it sinful on Mr. C's part to blindly believe a person's accusation.`
Blindly believing an innocent person to be a culprit might be harmful to the innocent person. For example a person  gets falsely accused of rape and most people blindly believe that he is a rapist and start shaming him. This might cause depression or sadness to the innocent person as he doesn't want to be called a rapist. In such a case the people blindly believing him to be a rapist, are those people bound to a sin? I hope you get my point.

Comment: Question: What really you refer to as a sin? Some heinous crime like murder etc or even day to day actions like cheating, treachery, infidelity etc ?

Comment: @Just_Do_It Any kind of worong doing, such as cheating, robbing, murder, harassment, blind judgement etc. I refer to as a sin.

Comment: By judging do you mean 1) to form an opinion about (something or someone) after careful thought 2) law : to make an official decision about (a legal case)? Both are very different.

Comment: @sv. I've edited my question which might answer your question.

Comment: Ok. Looks better now. I asked because the answer below appears to be assuming the second meaning i.e., a legal case where an appointed judge makes a wrong judgement. But you are simply asking if in general people should be judging others without proper understanding. Correct?

Comment: @sv. Yes that is correct

Answer (score 6):

Yes, judging wrongly is a sin or a crime.

In Hinduism, the responsibility of passing judgement (punishing wrong-doers) rests on the king.

For invisible crimes/sins the responsibility, however, rests on Yama the God of Karma and death.

A king maintains a council (parishad) comprised of Brahmins who are well versed in Srutis and the Smritis, to be able to prescribe the most appropriate punishments for a crime.

There are two cases here:

**Case 1:**

This is the case where a person is actually guilty of committing a crime but does not get punished appropriately by the king and his council.

In this case, the king, the criminal, the judges and the witnesses each share 1/4th of the guilt.

> Manu smriti 8.18. One quarter of (the guilt of) an unjust (decision) falls on him who committed (the crime), one quarter on the (false) witness, one
>   quarter on all the judges, one quarter on the king.

**Case 2:**

Here some innocent person gets wrongly punished without committing any crime.

In this case the king is held totally responsible.

> Manu Smriti 9.249. When a king punishes an innocent (man), his guilt is considered as great as when he sets free a guilty man; but (he acquires) merit
>   when he punishes (justly